# How to slow "java.security.SecurityPermission" "authProvider.SunMSCAPI" Exception when get the KeyStore elements?

Tags: security, exception, applet, keystore, element

I am getting KeyStore elements like certificate name,expiry date,etc.from My Applet to JSP page.For that i created Id for Applet class in JSP and accessing.
(like 
              )
At that time i am getting "java.security.SecurityPermission" "authProvider.SunMSCAPI" Exception.How i can rectify this problem?

Comment: Have you checked your java.policy file? Are permissions given?

Comment: No.I wont change policy file.Because it will run client locations.Not in a particular location.So please tell me with out modifying Java.Policy file,how i will handle the exception?